# Passing data from Edit Text to Java Object,

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to register users using SQLLite 3, and I need help getting information from EditText to user object then registering users.

I tried this:

```
        private EditText inputLastname;
        private EditText inputEmail;
        private EditText inputPassword;
        private EditText inputCity;
        private EditText inputPhone;
        register_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    User user = new User();
                    user.setFirstname(inputFirstname.getText().toString());
                    user.setLastname(inputLastname.getText().toString());
                    user.setEmail(inputEmail.getText().toString());
                    user.setPassword(inputPassword.getText().toString());
                    user.setPhone(Integer.parseInt(inputPhone.getText().toString()));
                    user.setCity(inputCity.getText().toString());

                    if (user != null) {

                        Log.d("message", user.toString().trim());// check if user is populated
                        databaseManager.createUser(user);// create user method
                        Toast toast =
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), user.toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.setMargin(50, 50);
                        toast.show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), login.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(register.this, "Registration Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    System.out.print(ex.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

Does anyone know a better/working way of doing this?

Comment: can you add log of error?

Comment: No error is displayed..

Comment: show `onCreate` method

Comment: Your code doesnt make sense. The user object can't be null. I would start by checking if all your input fields are really not null. Most likely, something in there throws a Null Pointer Exception. So, there *should* be some sort of logs. And without logs, we cant help you.

Comment: I think you might have forgotten the:
inputFirstname = findViewById(R.id.inputFirstname);

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

Comment: Any Advice on logging the user object or error,

Comment: where happens your fail?

Comment: the Exception is not shown on the debug, so its very hard to find where the error is in terms of the EditText's

Comment: I found the output of the operation:  "D/message: com.example.cis15_084.Assignment.User@fd519", as you can see the package name of the project is displayed,

Comment: Database operation in UI is not a good idea. And the process fails is too vague. There are many cases that can be failed: the user is not created in database; user created but activity is not started. By the way, login.class is not correct on many levels, it's small cases class and we can't tell whether it's an `Activity` class.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the initialization of pointing your EditText variables to the widgets in the layout. You should do this in your onCreate method. Once you do that you can use the `getText().toString()` on those variables to get the strings.

For example

```java
    private EditText inputLastname;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private EditText inputCity;
    private EditText inputPhone;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_groups, container, false);

        // Do this for every view
        inputEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.email_edit_text_id);
        ...

        return view;
    }
```